# What is the probability of the two aspirants?

Tags: probability

A company needs to fill two jobs and fifty aspirants are presented. Thirty of the applicants are affiliated and the rest are not. If two people are chosen at random, calculate the probability that:

1. None of the chosen is affiliated,
2. one of the two is affiliated,
3. the two are affiliated

My Solution:

Total of aspirants=50

Aspirants with affiliation=30

Aspirants without affiliation=20

1. P=$\frac{\binom{20}{2}}{\binom{50}{2}}=0.1551$
2. P=$\frac{\binom{30}{1}+\binom{20}{1}}{\binom{50}{2}}=0.04081$
3. P=$\frac{\binom{30}{2}}{\binom{50}{2}}=0.3551$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Given as they don't add up to 1, it can't be right

Comment: Your answers for 1 and 3 are correct. The answer for 2 just needs the binomial coefficients in the numerator to be multiplied instead of added. Are you familiar with the hypergeometric distribution? If so, the answers follows from the pmf directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these are the only 3 possible oucomes, their probabilities should add up to 1, and they don't, so you can immediately tell *something* is wrong.

Here is what is wrong:

In 2. you should *multiply* $30\choose1$ and $20\choose1$ in the numerator.